# Center TextView with drawableTop in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Here's how it's looking at the moment. [image]

I've read the other solutions offered here but none really helped.  I want to center those 4 textview with it's according drawable in the center horizontally and vertically of the LinearLayout. On mobile everything works fine, but on tablet, the bottom bar has a higher height and i want the controls to be centered.

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAreaTools"
                style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                android:layout_weight="0.19"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/area_tool"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
                android:text="@string/area" />

            <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                android:id="@+id/clearAllTool"
                style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                android:layout_weight="0.19"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.19"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtToggleNumbers"
                        style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/hide_numbers_tool" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                            android:id="@+id/mCalibrateToolView"
                            style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
                            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/show_calibrate_tool"
                            android:text="@string/calibrate_text" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/badgeRadius"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/calibrate_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/calibrate_size"
                            android:textColor="@color/primary_color"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mCalibrateToolView"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/calibrate_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/calibrate_margin_top"
                            android:background="@drawable/shape_notification"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                android:id="@+id/btnCount"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                style="@style/AreaToolButton"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:background="#33FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/count_text" />

            <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTagTools"
                style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                android:layout_weight="0.19"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/tags_tool"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/tags" />

            <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                android:id="@+id/menuTool"
                style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                android:layout_weight="0.19"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/bottom_more_count"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
                android:text="@string/more" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: At top level `LinearLayout`, `android:gravity="center_vertical"` Didn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. There's no visual difference

Comment: did you tried `layout_gravity`?

Comment: Yes Vivek, same result, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in yours:

```
<com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
      android:id="@+id/txtAreaTools"
      style="@style/BottomBarButton"
      android:layout_weight="0.19"
      android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/area_tool"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
      android:text="@string/area" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Doesn't work. Here's how it looks now (http://imgur.com/a/S2frs) The idea is that the icon and the text to be centered vertically, and right now the text is very low positioned. If the weight of that bottom bar is higher, the distance between the image and the text will be larger.

Comment: @ZackKaytranada i am not able to see image you linked in comment so i couldn't get any idea what happened after above change.

Comment: Only the text is centered vertically, the image is on the upper side of the view

Comment: since you are setting your image as `android:drawableTop="@drawable/bottom_more_count"` `drawableTop` means it will remain on top.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replace your code with this ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAreaTools"
            style="@style/BottomBarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/area_tool"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/area"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
            android:id="@+id/clearAllTool"
            style="@style/BottomBarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtToggleNumbers"
                style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/hide_numbers_tool"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
                    android:id="@+id/mCalibrateToolView"
                    style="@style/BottomBarButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/show_calibrate_tool"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/calibrate_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badgeRadius"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/calibrate_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/calibrate_size"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mCalibrateToolView"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/calibrate_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/calibrate_margin_top"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_notification"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_color"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">


        <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
            android:id="@+id/btnCount"
            style="@style/AreaToolButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#33FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/count_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTagTools"
            style="@style/BottomBarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_back_with_arrow"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/tags_tool"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tags"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.dyve.counting.widget.DVTextView
            android:id="@+id/menuTool"
            style="@style/BottomBarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/bottom_more_count"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/more"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_bar_text_size" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDITTED ::**

Wrapped the all view with a framelayout with that weight over that..so your inner views wont expand that much...
Try the new editted code..

Please tell if more help needed..

Comment: Here's how it looks (http://imgur.com/a/S2frs) The idea is that the icon and the text to be centered vertically, and right now the text is very low positioned. If the weight of that bottom bar is higher, the distance between the image and the text will be larger.